# What's the result of an integer list plus an integer in C?

Tags: c

I should post the complete code.

```
int f(int x, int *y) {
   static int a =0;
   int b =0;
   while(b<x) {
       a =a +y[b];
       b =b +1;
   }
   return a;
 }
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
     int z[5] ={1,2,3,4,5};
     int r1, r2;
     r1 =f(3, z);
     r2 =f(1, z+1);
 }
```

The value of r2 is 8. What is z+1 here?

Comment: Compile time error: `assignment to expression with array type`

Comment: `z` is a constant here, so you can't add to it. If it were a variable, then adding one to it would make a pointer to the second element in the array.

Comment: it's the same as `&z[1]`

Comment: [Possible duplicate here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161209/can-we-add-an-array-variable-to-integer)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `z+1` is an example of **pointer arithmetic**.

The array `z` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. `&z[0]`.  `z+1` means "take the address contained at `z` and add 1 array element to that address".  This is the same as `&z[1]`.

So this function call:

```
r1 =f(3, z);
```

Passes in the address of the first element of `z`, resulting in the array `z` being visible in the function.

In this function call:

```
r2 =f(1, z+1);
```

It passes in the address of the second element of `z`.  So the function is able to see the array starting from the second element.